# how to get context of views in view container in angular

Tags: angular6

In the following example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8udwh

I have created `EmbeddedViews` in the `ViewContainer`. When creating the views, I pass a context object and when deleting the views, I use the context to find index of the view and delete it from the view container. This works fine.

I have added a button which when clicked should print the info of views currently in the container. I can find the length and views in the container using the APIs of `ViewContainer` but how do I get the context object from the views?

This is the function I am unable to write

```
printViewInfo(){
    //I want to get all the views which are currently in the container and print their context objects.
    let length = this.vc.length
    for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
      let view = this.vc.get(i);
      //how to get the context back here from view??
    }
  }
```

What is the way to find context of views in a ViewContainer? I see that `get` returns a `ViewRef` and the `ViewRef` doesn't contain context. But `ViewContainerRef` doesn't provide APIs which return an `EmbeddedViewRef`

Answer (score -1):

I got this working by typecasting the `ViewRef` into `EmbeddedViewRef<any>`. Is this the right way? My concern is that if a `ViewContainerRef` contains both `EmbeddedView` and `ComponentView` then how will I distinguish between them? Or would it be a wrong design to use both `EmbeddedView` and `ComponentView` in the same `ViewContainer`?

```
printViewInfo(){
    //I want to get all the views which are currently in the container and print their context objects.
    let length = this.vc.length
    for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
      let view = <EmbeddedViewRef<any>> this.vc.get(i);
      //how to get the context back here from view??
      console.log("view.context.option ",view.context.option.description);
    }
  }
```